# Get line numbers of Xml attribute / opener tag using Sax Parser

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

I found a way to get starting and ending line numbers of Element nodes through overloading DefaultHandler. But how to get line numbers of attributes? If there is no way to do it, how to get line numbers of opener tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to parse XML via SAX/DOM with line numbers available per node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798376/is-there-a-way-to-parse-xml-via-sax-dom-with-line-numbers-available-per-node)

Comment: No, I already have it. He just wants to get line numbers of nodes (=elements)